# Series Word Problem

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

So the questions is:

A ball dropped from a height of 13 feet begins to bounce. Each time it strikes the ground, it returns to $\frac 34$ of its previous height. What is the total distance traveled by the ball if it bounces infinitely many times?
So I have been trying to reason out this problem. Since the ball returns to $\frac 34$ of the previous height, I think I have to do $\frac 34$ (the previous height).

Since the height starts at 13, the first height is going to be 13$\frac 34$. 
The next, $\frac{39}{4}$$\frac 34$

The next, $\frac{117}{16}$$\frac 34$...and so on.

So, I am just having trouble with expressing it in a summation notation. 
How do I express that from 0 to infinity in a summation notation?

Comment: Hi new user. Welcome to MSE! You might want to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) in future :)

Comment: Also, please show your working so far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a geometric series:

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} (\frac{3}{4})^{i} h $$

Answer (score 0):

The following modified geometric series describes the distance covered by the ball:

$$ h + 2 * \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} (\frac{3}{4})^{i} h \quad (\quad = 2 * \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} ( (\frac{3}{4})^{i} h ) - h\quad)$$

Explanation: each height is covered twice (by the rebound and the drop that immediately follows), apart from $h$ itself (immediately after the ball is dropped).